# msp430 communication with computer

Tags: embedded, usb, communication, msp430

I am trying to communicate with my MSP430F5529 LaunchPad which i just got to learn about microcontrollers and having some serious issues.

I downloaded the MSP430 USB Developer Package with examples from Texas Instruments and am using IAR as my IDE.

Inside the examples folder there are the same examples for different protocols it looks like: HID, CDC, Composite, MSC, and SYSBIOS.

I decided to hit HID and inside that folder explored the DataPipe folder and went to H0_SimpleSend which seems like the first and most basic example project.

Inside that it appears to have many folders and files for the project  such as USB_Config, USB_app, IAR, GCC, CCS_GCC, CSS, and the files system_pre_init.c, main.c, hal.h, and hal.c.

Inside the IAR folder is a project and workspace file so i loaded the up the project hoping it was as simple as being able to build the project onto my board and run debug while using Termite to communicate with a COM port.

When i plug in my MSP430F5529LP windows has two COM ports used, one says MSP Application UART1, and one says MSP Debug Interface and they are always consecutive COM ports (either COM11 and COM10, respectively, or COM12 and COM13, respectively.). I assume i want the UART one so i set Termite to communicated with the Application UART1 with 8 bits of data nd 1 stop bit, no parity bits.

Then i built the program, which built fine, and loaded it onto my board.

Stepping through the program it never seems to work. it always gets stuck on this block:

```
// This function begins the USB send operation, and immediately
// returns, while the sending happens in the background.
// Send timeStr, 9 bytes, to intf #0 (which is enumerated as a
// COM port).  1000 retries.  (Retries will be attempted if the
// previous send hasn't completed yet).  If the bus isn't present,
// it simply returns and does nothing.
if (USBCDC_sendDataInBackground(timeStr, 9, CDC0_INTFNUM, 1000))
{
_NOP();  // If it fails, it'll end up here.  Could happen if
// the cable was detached after the connectionState()
}           // check, or if somehow the retries failed
```

And sometimes during the debug session windows will say that my device has been disconected.

What am i doing wrong?

I am not sure what all those protocols are, what is CDC or HID and why would i use one over the other. It seems like USB communication is very complex... Energia and Arduino make it seem so easy with Begin.Serial(9600) but I want to learn the "real" way with IAR since i am beginner a career in embedded systems.

Should i try to proceed and make this work? or is there material i need to understand first before I can attempt to get usb communication working?

I don't want to do anything too lofty with the USB, i just want to use the ADC12 to read a signal off a resistive force sensor, and then shoot that data over to the computer.

To see all the code im talking about you can download Texas Instruments example folder [here](http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP430_USB_Developers_Package/latest/exports/MSP430USBDevelopersPackage_5_00_01.zip) [**Warning**: Link starts download, to see page where i came from go [here](http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSP430_USB_Developers_Package/latest/index_FDS.html)).

Comment: HID is human interface device, a type of USB peripheral. Perhaps the example project is implementing an actual USB HID peripheral rather than the serial port interface you're expecting.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice intro to USB and its sub-protocols. Also, the specs are free for download. If you want to play with an MCU you should learn how to. As given, I'd say the question is either too broad or lacking more information and a _specific_ problem. And, no we will not down load tons of vendor bloat. Plase provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf to provide a MCVE would require all the libraries related to the example program.

Comment: So the better alternative would be? To read what USB actually **is**, what HID and CDC mean. IOW: read the specs!

Answer (score 0):

USB is a rather complex set of protocols.

The USB protocol for COM ports is called CDC (communication device class), not HID.

When you implement a (virtual) COM port on the F5529, it shows up as a *third* port on the host PC.

The F5529 has two 'real' UARTs.
The first one goes to the BoosterPack connector.
The second one is connected to the eZ-FET CPU, which implements a UART-to-USB interface; this is the "Application" UART.

Using the application UART is easier because you don't have to implement a USB device; you just use the USCI_A1 module directly, and the other CPU takes care of the USB stuff.

Read sections 2.2.3 and 2.2.6 of your LaunchPad's user guide.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I looked into the user's guide and have a little better idea of what i need to do, but i still find that there is a serious lack of tutorials/guides for beginners to learn about usb communication with this device. The guide says you need to create your own instance of a usb module for an application to communicate with but doesn't say how at all, and the examples TI provides don't seem to do any of that.

Comment: also what exactly is HID for then if not for communication with COM ports?

Comment: As I said, USB is complex; if you don't use the CDC/HID/MSC examples, you must know all those USB protocols, and the MSP430 hardware, to be able to write your own implementation. Human Interface Devices are things like keyboards and mice.